# Is pixel based image encryption secure?

Tags: encryption, passwords

I have encrypted an image using pixel encryption method. I just used a bmp image for that. What I did is, I retrieved each pixel value from the image and obtained the value of red, green and blue value individually and XOR-ed it with a pseudo random value. For pseudo random number generation I used the SecureRandom with the SHA1PRNG algorithm. The seed value set for generating the random numbers is obtained from the password that we give.

Detailed description of the code and the ouput is available in [zone4java](http://zone4java.blogspot.in/2013/03/simple-secure-image-encryption-and.html)

My question is how long will it take to any utility, if available, to decrypt the image without knowing the password? Is this kind of encryption methods secure?

Note: If my question is being downvoted, please comment the reason.

Comment: Regardless of how good you think your homemade scheme is, don't roll your own crypto. Why are you encrypting each pixel individually rather than encrypting the entire image as a byte stream? Do you have a good reason for doing so?

Comment: @TerryChia If i encrypt the file, the image viewing application may not be able to read it as image file. And also as futher part i can create shares of this image and it goes.

Comment: Why would you go out of your way to allow image viewers to be able to display it?

Comment: Very tempted to close as not a real question. This isn't about whether you encrypt per pixel or using more common methods. From a security perspective it is about the algorithm, and the choice of password. The rest here is irrelevant.

Comment: @StephenTouset I wanted the output of my encryption a image file itself. So that i can work on that, like making image shares and hiding data etc.

Comment: @Maximin Your question is being downvoted because this StackExchange is filled with repeated questions of the template: "I've invented my own encryption approach. How hard is it to break?" The approach is inevitably weaker, slower, less useful than existing approaches, not extensively analyzed by professionals, and contains obvious weaknesses that don't revolve around brute-forcing a key. On top of this, you've taken the extra step of publishing your method on a weblog with no disclaimer against its use, further encouraging the already-widespread problem of poor encryption practice.

Comment: There are obvious reasons for this. Encrypting an image by pixel can be used in many scenarios. For example, live streaming video where sections are blurred for certain viewers but not others. Sharing images containing sensitive information publicly by encrypting the parts you don't want public, such as part of a face or an address; the applications are many. I'm also not sure how image encryption could be brute forced since you'd need image recognition software to find the right arrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting the pixels in a bitmap by xor-ing with the output of a stream cipher is okay in principle, but there are a number of caveats:

1. You don't encrypt the size of the image, or any meta-data.
2. Like with all stream-ciphers you must never reuse a key (or key-nonce pair). In your case this means you must never reuse a seed.

   Else you get a many-time-pad, which sucks. So you need some way to include a nonce.
3. `SHA1PRNG` isn't the best choice for a stream cipher. The biggest problem is that the implementation might change between different versions. I believe this happened on android, breaking some applications.

   You should use an designated stream cipher, like AES in CTR mode, not a PRNG.
4. Since you're using password based encryption, you need a proper password based KDF, such as PBKDF2 with sufficient iterations and a salt. I recommend using a random 16 byte salt.

   Using a unique salts here leads to unique keys for the cipher, so you don't need the nonce I mentioned in step 2 anymore. Effectively the salt is the nonce.

Comment: BMP does not contain metadata.

Comment: @forest While it doesn't contain exif style metadata, it can contain quite a bit of data apart from the pixels itself. Image size, colordepth, color tables, color profiles, pixel density,...

Answer (score 2):

The first image is of Tux, the Linux mascot. The second image is of Tux, encrypted in ECB mode (more or less what you're attempting). The third is of Tux, encrypted in CBC mode. The problem with the second approach as well as your own is that identical pixel values encrypt to the same value in ciphertext. So even though the *color* of each pixel is protected, the underlying pattern is easily visible.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Do yourself a favor, and don't roll your own crypto. Use something well-established like AES in CBC mode, or (ideally) GCM mode. And encrypt the *entire* byte stream in one go, rather than trying to be clever and encrypt pixel by pixel.

Comment: I have provided a link in the question where you can see the code and output for the asked method of encryption. When i encrypt the image, I will get the encrypted image similar to that of the third image. Sorry, please go through every detail. Thank you

Comment: From your code, you're using a simple password to encrypt. This is going to be orders of magnitude easier to brute-force than a proper key. There is no initialization vector, so any re-use of a password will create an identical keystream. Encrypting each color value separately is pointless and just triples the already-poor running time for the algorithm. Again: don't roll your own crypto. Use something well-established that's been peer-reviewed. There is zero reason to believe that any algorithm, particularly a homegrown one, is secure until it has been analyzed by professional cryptographers.

Comment: `openssl enc -aes-128-gcm -in /path/to/image -out /path/to/encrypted_image` is shorter, simpler, faster, more secure, uses a strong KDF to prevent brute-forcing the password, doesn't replay to an identical ciphertext, and works for any image format (and *any* other type of file for that matter). The wheel need not be reinvented, poorly.

Comment: Ofcourse the password will create the identical stream, that is used to decrypt the image. I am not saying this method is the best. All I want to know is how far is this secure. In openssl enc how it is going to decypt the image?

Comment: @Maximin A- Not secure. B- You can decrypt simply by doing `openssl enc -d -aes-128-gcm -in /path/to/encrypted_image`

Comment: My understanding is that the OP is using a stream cipher, so ECB weaknesses don't apply.